# Update column entries to remove the last character if it's an underscore

Tags: r, character

I want to remove the underscore **"_"** from the column entries of **col1** only when the underscore is the last character.

Example:

```
data1 <- c("foo_bar_","bar_foo","apple_","apple__beer_")
df <- data.frame("col1"=data1,"col2"=1:4)
df
```

```
        col1   col2
    foo_bar_      1
     bar_foo      2
      apple_      3
apple__beer_      4
```

**Desired output:**

```
        col1   col2
     foo_bar      1
     bar_foo      2
       apple      3
 apple__beer      4
```

Thank you in advance for your time and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `sub()` here for a base R option:

```r
df$col1 <- sub("_$", "", df$col1)
df

         col1 col2
1     foo_bar    1
2     bar_foo    2
3       apple    3
4 apple__beer    4
```

Answer (score 1):

For a `tidyverse` solution use `stringr::str_replace`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>%
  mutate(col1 = str_replace(col1, "_$", ""))

#          col1 col2
# 1     foo_bar    1
# 2     bar_foo    2
# 3       apple    3
# 4 apple__beer    4
```